# get android apk from react-native

Tags: react-native

*I try to get apk from react-native. when I try to do this in commmand prompt*

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin>cd android && ./gradlew
>   assembleRelease

*it says to me: *

> system file not found.

*I searched on web but nothing help me*

Comment: does your `bin` contain the `android` folder?

Comment: oh I did everything and when I enter password to command. it gives me thise error:     Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my-release-key.keystore -destkeystore my-release-key.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".

Comment: it looks like you are already past the issue you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs to be done in your project folder and not in jdk folder

first go to your Project folder

```
cd ~/Projects/React/YourProject
```

then do `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

apk files will be generated in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/`